# Hint menu does not appear for Range variable in VBA editor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this code:

```
Dim interface As Worksheet
Dim slope, measure As Range

Set interface = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
Set slope = interface.Range("G1")
Set measure = interface.Range("G2")
```

When I type `measure.` hint menu appears.

But when I type `slope.` nothing happens.

All the code is located in a module, not in the "Main" worksheet. It seems to me that Excel does not recognize slope as a range variable. I am really annoyed, and I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: there is a type error above, Set interface = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main") sorry about that set slope = interface.range("G1") set measure = interface.range("G2")

Comment: I made separate module only with this code, changing the slope to slope to slope_test but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have not declared a type for variable `slope`. In VBA, you cannot declare the type for a list of variables with one `as Range` statement. You must declare the type for each variable individually.

As a result, VBA is treating `slope` as a Variant for which it can provide no guidance for methods or properties with a hint menu.

Update your code to the following.

```
Dim slope as Range, measure As Range
```

Comment: @tetris555 You're welcome! If this answer worked for you, please consider marking this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. For more information on accepting answers, see [this help page](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).